# Where's the link to this Q&A site in the Tor Browser home page?

Tags: discussion

Previous versions of the Tor browser bundle used a home page that included a link to this Q&A site, but the current version uses a locally generated home page that doesn't include this link.  (I had to fire up an older version to find it again.)  I do understand that some of TPTB at Tor didn't see the need for this Q&A site when it was first created, however not including an easy-to-find link to it in TBB is something of a self-fulfilling prophesy, ensuring its failure.

Comment: At the moment there is none, but trac issue [#9888](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/9888) requests a link to the Q&A site.

Comment: I just pushed a little bit more on that ticket. I am also pondering how to get the Tor helpdesk folks -- at least, the ones who answer in English -- to push more of their questions and traffic over to SE, which would be more sustainable than "answer questions over and over in private".

Answer (score 0):

Keep pushing their help desk to open more tickets.

Remind them that they took away a useful feature and you simply think it should be put back in so our database can be more thoroughly built with good questions and answers.

Here's where the elevator speeech can come in handy.

But the bottom line is that **their original intent was to have that link there**, and somebody new probably just goofed.